# How to filter the output based on the output of count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

Tables in my database: **1. Employee**

[image: Employee table]

**2.Aircraft**

**[image: Certified table]**

**3.Certified**

[image]

Query: I need to find pilot name, eid, aircraft name, cruising_range where pilot is certified to fly more than 3 aircraft's . i wrote a query and it works but i want to know **if there is a simple way to achieve this** because my query seems much complicated .

**My query is :**

[image]

**Edit**: Corrected the name of tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that each AID in Certified had a corresponding value on Aircraft, then it can be done like this:

```
SELECT ename,employee.eid,aname,crusing_range
FROM employee JOIN certified
ON employee.eid = certified.eid
JOIN aircraft 
ON certified.aid = aircraft.aid
WHERE exists(select 1 FROM certified t
             WHERE t.eid = employee.eid
              GROUP BY t.eid HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3)
```

Comment: I think the OP mixed up the names of the last 2 tables, so in the subselect it should be the certified table, not the aircraft. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: it says unknown column s.eid in where clause.

Comment: And pls add the join conditions as well to the outer query and fix the alias in the subquery:)

Comment: The alias is incorrect in the subquery, you have only t defined, not s. Although the OP should have done the debugging as well.

Comment: oh sorry, that was a mistake .

Comment: Damn all those typos @Shadow and what join conditions are missing?

Comment: Nothing, I was wrong about the join condition. Mea culpa!

Comment: Its ok buddy, any ways Balrag the query should work now.

Comment: hey could you please explain a little bit , how the sub query is working because it seems that it will return a column of 1's and how that can be used for outer query ? @sagi

Comment: @Balraj It doesn't matter what it returns, it remember IF it return anything or not, thats the purpose of EXISTS(). It checks if for that employee there is atleast 3 records in certified. Basically I could write select username or any other column in the subquery and it would be exactly the same.

Comment: thanks again, if you could write this in answer it would help someone else who is not looking in comments. thanks @sagi

Answer (score 1):

Ahh man, don't prefix your columns with your table names. Just have employee ID column as id not eid

I would try this:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM aircraft A
LEFT JOIN employee E ON E.eid = A.eid
LEFT JOIN certified C ON C.aid = A.aid
Where SUM(A.eid) > 3
```

I'm on mobile but I hope it helps.

The key information is in the Aircraft table so start with that and then join the tables you want the extra bits from. Chucking a distinct on employee id within the SELECT will stop duplicates too.

Rethink table names too.

Comment: this query gave an error saying invalid use of group function.